# How to retrieve list of "My App" from Google Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

is it possible to retrieve the list of "My App" (included the uninstalled ones) from Google Play Store using Android SDK or external library?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is an API to gather information of your apps in the Google Play Store, but currently it is very limited:

`Currently, the API allows you to check the status of or cancel a user's subscription purchase.`

https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/index

Other than that, there is no official way to retrieve information from the Google Play Store regarding your own applications. It's possible that using Google Analytics (and its associated API) could help you solve your problem.

Comment: thank you very much, 
unfortunately these suggestions don't help me to resolve my issue.